# LibreOffice Calc time format

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I just have started using LibreOffice Calc, and facing one issue regarding time.
Let's say a cell's value is "30/01/15 05:00". Now when I'm using this cell in a formula(which is to CONCAT the values of cell), the result that I'm getting is in the form "42034.2083449074". But I want it to be in the same format as it is in the original value.

Answer (score 0):

With date and time in say A1 and some text in B1, then the two may be combined (eg text then date/time) with format for date and time specified with the TEXT function:

```
 =B1&TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yy hh:mm")
```

[Syntax](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#TEXT)

```
TEXT(Number; Format)
```

**Number** is the numerical value to be converted.

**Format** is the text which defines the format. Use decimal and thousands separators according to the language set in the cell format.
Example

`=TEXT(12.34567;"###.##")` returns the text 12.35

`=TEXT(12.34567;"000.00")` returns the text 012.35